# Where is the output file of python subprocess in hadoop streaming

Tags: python, subprocess, hdfs, hadoop-streaming, blast

I am using hadoop streaming running a c++ executable (a bioinformatic software called blast) with python subprocess. Blast will output a result file when executing on command line. But when running on hadoop, I can not find the output file of blast. I would like to know, where does the output file go??

My code (map.py) is as following:

```
# path used on hadoop
tool = './blastx'
reference_path = 'Reference.fa'

# input format example

# >LW1           (contig name)
# ATCGATCGATCG   (sequence)

# samile file: https://goo.gl/XTauAx

(name, seq) = (None, None)

for line in sys.stdin:

    # when detact the ">" sign, assign contig name
    if line[0] == '>':
        name = line.strip()[1:]

    # otherwise, assign the sequence
    else:
        seq = line.strip()

        if name and seq:

            # assign the path of output file
            output_file = join(current_path, 'tmp_output', name)

            # blast command example (export out file to a given path)
            command = 'echo -e \">%s\\n%s\" | %s -db %s -out %s -evalue 1e-10 -num_threads 16' % (name, seq, tool, reference_path, output_file)

            # execute command with python subprocess
            cmd = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)

            # retrieve the standard output of command
            cmd_out, cmd_err = cmd.communicate()

            print '%s\t%s' % (name, output_file)
```

The command for calling blast is:

```
command = 'echo -e \">%s\\n%s\" | %s -db %s -out %s -evalue 1e-10 -num_threads 16' % (name, seq, tool, reference_path, output_file)
```

Usually the output files are in the path of `output_file`, but I can not find them on both local file system and hdfs. It seems that they are created in a temporary directory, and disappear after the execution. How can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the output files of blast. It seems that they stay in the nodes where blast is executed. So after I put them back to hdfs, I could access them under the directory `/user/yarn`.
What I did is add the following code to `map.py`:

```
command = 'hadoop fs -put %s' % output_file
cmd = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

And I also modified the output path as

```
output_file = name
```

instead of using

```
output_file = join(current_path, 'tmp_output', name)
```

[Update on 3/3]
But putting files under user yarn directory is not good, because normal user has no permission to edit the file under the directory. I recommend putting files into `/tmp/blast_tmp` by changing command to

```
command = 'hadoop fs -put %s /tmp/blast_tmp' % output_file
```

Before that, the directory `/tmp/blast_tmp` should be created with

```
% hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/blast_tmp
```

and change the permission of the directory by

```
% hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/blast_tmp
```

in this case, both the user yarn and you can access the directory.